# How to make a document with light colors printer friendly?

Tags: color, moderncv, printing

I have a document with some text in light colors. It's looking good on screen but I need to print it. Unfortunately, once printed on a black and white laser printer, the light blue is no longer legible due to dithering.

How can I render a document in which the text is going to be correct once printed ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}

\firstname{F}
\familyname{T}
\title{Title}
\address{43}{City}
\mobile{112-555-555}
\email{<mail>}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Blue text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post an MWE (minimum working example, beginning with `\documentclass` and `\end{document}) that illustrates how you generate colored text.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
\usepackage[gray]{xcolor}
```

It should convert all colors into grayscale. `moderncv`  already loads `xcolor` with own options. Use in this case:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{F}
\familyname{T}
\title{Title}
\address{43}{City}
\mobile{112-555-555}
\email{<mail>}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Blue text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see my edited answer.

Comment: If you don't want gray then use `\moderncvtheme[black]{classic}`

Comment: Yes I guess that's a solution too. I was initially looking for a generic solution, but if it's working I'll accept it. Can you think of a solution working on a PDF file ?

Comment: Why should the above not work with a pdf file??

Comment: I meant: do something on the PDF file (like alter the color of text) after it's been compiled. But it's a bit out of the scope of tex.se I think.

Comment: Acrobat can do it